# How to formally use Taylor expansions for $n$th derivatives and generating functions?

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, power-series, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

When deriving [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), the generating function takes on this form:

$$C(x) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - \sqrt{1-4x}) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - f(x))$$

where $f(x) = \sqrt{1-4x}$

How does one formally show what it evaluates to? I can do it somewhat "informally" like so:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1-4x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$$

$$f(x) = \frac{f^{(0)}(0)}{0!} x^0 + \frac{f^{(1)}(0)}{1!} x^1 + \frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!} x^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!} x^3 + \frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!} x^4 + ...$$

Now at this point I can literally start computing the successive derivatives of $f(x)$ and then plug in $0$ for each $x$ and look for patterns and "eyeball" a closed-form for it.

But is there a way at this point to formally show what the $n$th derivative is? Or is this more of an art than a science that changes depending on the function?

I could eyeball the $n$th derivative formula as well:

$f^{0}(x) = (1 - 4x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$f^{1}(x) = (\frac{1}{2})(-4)(1 - 4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

$f^{2}(x) = (-\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})(-4)(-4)(1 - 4x)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

$f^{3}(x) = (-\frac{3}{2})(-\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})(-4)(-4)(-4)(1 - 4x)^{-\frac{5}{2}}$

$f^{4}(x) = (-\frac{5}{2})(-\frac{3}{2})(-\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})(-4)(-4)(-4)(-4)(1 - 4x)^{-\frac{7}{2}}$

At this point I can eyeball the pattern and solve it manually. But again, what if I couldn't do that? Is there a more direct and methodical way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, you could use the generalized binomial expansion $$(1+x)^a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{a}{n} x^n$$ which makes $$f(x)=\sqrt{1-4x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\binom{\frac 12}{n} (4x)^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\binom{\frac 12}{n} (4x)^n$$ and then $$C(x) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - \sqrt{1-4x})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\binom{\frac 12}{n} (4x)^n$$

Comment: How is the generalized binomial expansion going up to infinity? I thought that expansion only makes sense from $n=0$ up to $a$ in this case. Or is it technically $0$ for $n>a$ but it doesn't hurt to list the infinity for the sake of making it more consistent with how generating functions are handled?

Comment: Also how does $\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}$ work? A fraction in a binomial coefficient? Fractional factorials?

Comment: Take care : here, we consider that $a$ is not an integer. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series (search for *Binomial series*).

Comment: I see the equation but I still don't understand how that works. Why is it going up to infinity when the typical formula stops at the exponent on the lefthand side, integer or not? Why doesn't it stop at the floor (or ceiling) of $a$, etc?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer I'm trying but I am not confident that I am doing this correctly or seeing what I am supposed to be seeing.

Comment: But the earlier equation says $(1+x)^a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{a}{n} x^n$, which means $(1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-1}{n} x^n$. Just to clarify are you using $\binom{-1}{n} = (-1)^n \binom{-1+n-1}{n} = (-1)^n\binom{n}{n} = (-1)^n$?

Comment: Even so I don't know what I am supposed to be looking at